# Who are PhDs and PhD candidates on this site?

Tags: discussion

just wondering who are Econ Phds or Econ PhD students on the site. Obviously knowing anyone can claim anything. I just want to know if anyone here is an Econ PhD or Econ PhD student can you post below if you are and what your research interests are.

The reason I ask is really to understand if there is any real interest in me starting an Economics Overflow site. The requirement obviously would be to have some users with a little bit of "Above average" academic economics knowledge and interest.

Post below if you can!

Answer (score 9):

I am an econ PhD (working in IO).

I feel a little pessimistic about the viability of an econ overflow site. We initially tried to moderate this site to be focused on professional-level economics, but without much success. An overflow site would also be competing with the likes of EconSpark, which has the backing of the AEA but nevertheless seems to be failing.

Comment: The reason why i think econ spark isnt taking off is mainly due to access to the site.

Comment: @EconJohn What do you mean by access to the site?

Comment: basically your account is under review and you are basically stuck in spectator mode, so you cant post a question or create an answer to existing questions. I personally have had my account under review for almost a year now so it seems unaccessible IMO.

Comment: @EconJohn I see. That's very different to my experience: my account was approved almost instantly.

Comment: Same here, account was approved immediately. What sucks there is that the association set up the forum to compete with the infamous econjobrumors.com site with the intent to especially fight sexism but they hardly spend any effort to give it a particular added value like making it the place where important news is announced first or where influential economists or at least association representatives answer questions or anything like that. Who needs just another forum with some association tag on it?

Comment: Same here but maybe it’s contingent on being AEA member? I also noticed that EconSpark has become a ghost town such shame it looked as a such great and wholesome project

Answer (score 8):

I am a recent Econ PhD graduate with research interests primarily in public finance. Like Ubiquitous, I also feel pessimistic about the viability of an econ overflow site.

Answer (score 6):

I am an econ PhD, working in the fields of econometrics/stochastic frontier analysis and macroeconomics.

Answer (score 6):

Econ PhD specializing on methodology and transparency of research, in particular replicability.

Answer (score 6):

Econ PhD, working on microeconomic theory.

Answer (score 5):

Im an Econ PhD candidate.  My research interests are in consumer behaviour and demand system estimation.

I envision econ overflow being a much more demanding site source wise where people can post research problems they are working on.

Answer (score 5):

Ph.D. whose research is in finance.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a PhD in environmental and resource economics. My MSc is in forest and nature conservation though, so I'm hardly a standard economist.

Answer (score 5):

Do I still count as PhD student if I had to put my graduate program on hold due to medical reasons? I have MSc. In international economics and second MSc. in Policy economics though. My research interests are macroeconomics, financial stability and hysteresis.

Answer (score 5):

PhD in Economics/Finance with research in applied financial econometrics and risk management.