# Removing the beta label from Economics.SE

Tags: feature-request

We have been a beta site for 2031 days, just over 5.5 years at this point. Taking a look at our recent statistics:

[image]

The criteria regarding questions per day has been fairly healthy, even with some seasonality. Traffic is good and some of the more technical questions are what contributes to the % of questions answered and answer ratio. Many of these criterion are flexible as I understand it, in that we do not need to hit every benchmark in order to become a full site.

Our community has a relatively focused core of knowledgeable users who can consistently run a modestly sized stack with meaningful contributions to knowledge on economics. Other economics forum sites don't accomplish the same sort of discourse and activity that we do (e.g. Econ Job rumors, EconSpark, etc.). I think as is, we would be able to sustain ourselves healthily if we were to be promoted to a full site now, but I also think becoming a proper full site would be a boon to us in terms of our credibility and activity in the Stack community as a whole.

Therefore, I am tagging this question as [status-review](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review) to petition the staff to consider us for the removal of the beta label. This is also a call to arms for those who would like to see us become a full site to **post an answer with your own thoughts for why we should become a full site**, or to just vocalize your support. And of course, even though we are not always a high voting site (:P) please give an **upvote if you approve of this proposal**.

Comment: Both "76% answered" and "1.6 answer ratio" are better than what I see on other StackExchange sites which do have a "beta" label.

Comment: Note: here's [the answer from the CM (as of May 2020) about the current status of the future graduation plan on SE](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/444/1625), as a response to the same request on Latin.SE's request.

Answer (score 6):

Becoming a full fledged site I think is deserving since we have a solid base of [experts](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1940/who-are-phds-and-phd-candidates-on-this-site) and seem to be currently the only real site out there which has intelligent posts regarding economic theory.

I can personally say that I've gained a lot from the site having been on the site since I was an undergraduate student. Additionally I think that smart questions and answers are posted here which are beneficial not only for the student but for the researcher as well.

Comment: I'd think your statement that "the only real site out there which has intelligent posts regarding economic theory." is probably overstretching it. There are a lot of good sites where economists post or blog about economic theory. It may be true for Q&A sites (I'm not a visitor of other Econspark or Jub rumours so I wouldn't know).

Comment: @MaartenPunt I agree that there are lot of intelligent blogs and so on out there but not really Q&A site. JMR can be extremely toxic and EconSpark is dead town - almost all posts there with one or two exceptions in the last month were just updates on various surveys from one single user. https://www.aeaweb.org/forum/

Answer (score 2):

As [this comment](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/removing-the-beta-label-from-economics-se#comment3782_2006) and [Catija's answer over at the Latin site](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/444/6) denote, the future of sites in beta such as Economics is in flux for the time being — as Catija did back in May on Latin, I'll ask for your patience on this matter. This is something I'd like to see prioritized too, and [the recent news about fundraising and opening of new CM positions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351385/208518) will hopefully be a step forward in being able to get this moving again.